# Displaying empty/new record on open

Tags: filemaker

I am relatively new to Filemaker so this may be easy for some of you. I am making an IT Ticketing System and I want every user not an Admin (so basically everyone will be a guest) to just see a new, blank record when they enter the database. I tried to script below but when I log into FM Web Direct, it doesn't work.

```
If [Get(AccountName)="Guest"]
  Go To Layout [LayoutName]
  New Record/Request
  Show/Hide Menubar [Hide]
  Show/Hide Toolbars [Hide]
End If
```

I set the script to run on OnFirstWindowOpen (I've also tried OnWindowOpen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match the guest account, you need to include the brackets, like this: [Guest]